# Using Stripe SDK for creditcards

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments

I'm trying to use Stripe and it's working. There's just one problem. I've got a 
STPPaymentCardTextField and I send the cardParams to the their backend like so:

```
STPAPIClient.sharedClient().createTokenWithCard(paymentTextField.cardParams) { (token, error) -> Void in
            if let error = error  {
                HUD.flash(.Error, delay:1.0, completion: {(done) in
                })
                print(error)
            }
            else if let token = token {

            }
        }
```

I however need to know the cardtype (Visa, Amex, Mastercard etc.) as well. This can only be retrieved by using the STPCard object. I do not know how to cast my STPCardParams object into a STPCard object to get this data.

Comment: You can use the `brandForNumber` class method in `STPCardValidator`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Paulw11's comment I found this to be what I'm looking for:

```
STPAPIClient.sharedClient().createTokenWithCard(paymentTextField.cardParams) { (token, error) -> Void in
            if let error = error  {
                HUD.flash(.Error, delay:1.0, completion: {(done) in
                })
                print(error)
            }
            else if let token = token {

            let brandTypeID = STPCardValidator.brandForNumber(self.paymentTextField.cardNumber!).rawValue

            }
        }
```